# structs with uint8_t on a MCU without uint8_t datatype

Tags: c, embedded, uint8t

I am an Embedded Software developer and I want to interface to an external device. This device sends data via SPI. The structure of that data is predefined from the external device manufacturer and can't be edited. The manufacturer is providing some Header files with many typedefs of all the data send via SPI.
The manufacturer also offers an API to handle the received packets in the correct way(I have access to the source of that API).

Now to my problem:
The typedefed structures contain many uint8_t datatypes. Unfortunately, our MCU doesn't support uint8_t datatypes, because the smallest type is 16bit-wide(so even a char has 16-bit).

To use the API correctly the structures must be filled with the data received via SPI. Since the incoming data is byte-packet, we can't just copy this data into the struct, because our structs use 16-bit for those 8-bit types.
As a result, we need to do many bitshift-operations to assign the received data correctly.

**EXAMPLE:**(manufacturers typedef struct)

```
typedef struct NETX_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_INFOtag
{
  uint8_t   bChannelType;              //uint16_t in our system
  uint8_t   bChannelId;                //uint16_t in our system
  uint8_t   bSizePositionOfHandshake;  //uint16_t in our system
  uint8_t   bNumberOfBlocks;           //uint16_t in our system
  uint32_t  ulSizeOfChannel;           
  uint16_t  usCommunicationClass;      
  uint16_t  usProtocolClass;           
  uint16_t  usProtocolConformanceClass;
  uint8_t   abReserved[2];             //uint16_t in our system
} NETX_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_INFO;
```

Can anybody think of an easy workaround to this problem?
I really don't want to write a separate bitshift operation for every received packet type. (performance/time/space-waste)

**My Idea**
(using bitfields to stuff 2xuint8_t into uint16_t or 4xuint8_t into uint32_t)

```
typedef struct NETX_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_INFOtag
{
  struct packet_uint8{
    uint32_t  bChannelType              :8;
    uint32_t  bChannelId                :8;
    uint32_t  bSizePositionOfHandshake  :8;
    uint32_t  bNumberOfBlocks           :8;
  }packet_uint8;
  uint32_t  ulSizeOfChannel;               
  uint16_t  usCommunicationClass;          
  uint16_t  usProtocolClass;               
  uint16_t  usProtocolConformanceClass;    
  uint16_t  abReserved;                    
} NETX_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_INFO;
```

Now I am not sure if this solution is going to work since the order of the bits inside the bitfield is not necessarily the order in the source file. (or is it if all the bitfields have the same size?)

I hope I described the problem well enough for you to understand.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: You're saying that your MCU doesn't support uint8_t. But from your description it rather sounds as if your C compiler had severe limitations. Even if your MCU has some limitations, the C compiler could still use a variety of commands to implement byte operations. It's very difficult to help you without knowing the limitations of the C compiler. Do you have a link to the description of the compiler limitations? What MCU are you using?

Comment: You're **either** writing C++ **or** C. Pick your pill :D

Comment: This is the compiler-description:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514q/spru514q.pdf
See 6.4 for Compilertypes and maybe 16.15.4 for some compiler typedefs that might help, but I don't understand those.
The MCU is the TMS320F28379D

Comment: Chapter 6.15.6 in that manual suggest the same approach, of using bitfields. If you don't need properties of the `bp_16` type as described in chapter 6.15.6, you can likely still use uint16_t for the bitfields. The manual does not seem to describe the order of the bitfields though , you will have to determine that yourself by experimentation , although examples from the same chapter suggests bitfields are laid out as they are in source code.

Comment: According to documentation the compiler supports c++03: The compiler
uses
the C++03
version
of the C++ standard

Comment: The solution is to not use exotic junk from TI. Or better yet, don't use anything at all from TI, since they have non-existent support and hate customers. If it was a part from someone else, you could simply have asked their support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *compiler manual* should describe how the bit fields are laid out. Read it carefully. There is something called `__attribute__((byte_peripheral))` too that should help with packing bitfields sanely in memory-mapped devices.

---

If you're unsure about the *bitfields*, just use `uint16_t` for these fields and an access macro with bit shifts, for example

```
#define FIRST(x) ((x) >> 8)
#define SECOND(x) ((x) & 0xFF)

...
    uint16_t channel_type_and_id;
...

int channel_type = FIRST(x->channel_type_and_id);
int channel_id = SECOND(x->channel_type_and_id);
```

Then you just need to be sure of the byte-order of the platform. If you need to change endianness which the MCU seems to support? you can just redefine these macros.

---

A bitfield would most probably still be implemented in terms of bitshifts so there wouldn't be much savings - and if there *are* byte-access functions for registers, then a compiler would know to optimize `x & 0xff` to use them

Comment: Why use a macro if you have c++ ?

Comment: @darune Actually,  same for C. (Considering the question is double-tagged...)

Comment: @darune what C++, the question has C tag.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It also, until very recently, had the C++ tag.

Comment: @MaxLanghof my answer is in C. And I don't get the number of downvotes given that it is correct. I've also asked for clarification whether C or C++ should be used.

Comment: Sorry I just deleted the C++ tag.

Comment: You get downvoted because most function-like macros shouldn't be written. This is 2018, i.e. C99 is 19 years old.

Comment: The headling of the linked to document says it is a "C/C++" compiler.

Comment: @NickyC and C17 is much less!

Comment: I mentioned C99 because inline function was introduced in C99.

Comment: @NickyC and *how about* the `__byte()` intrinsic... now that you've got the inline function, we cannot use that unless the compiler is very very clever.

Comment: I am talking about the two function-like macros in your post. Don't play strawman.

Comment: @M.M There is zero benefit of the macro in this case - an inline function can do the same and therefore fits the bill better (there are multiple downsides to macros compared to functions).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala why use a macro when you have inline functions ? there are many downsides with macros as compared to a function.

Comment: @darune I wrote a macro explicitly to access the "first" and "second" bytes of a struct field. One reason to use a macro might be that it can be written as generic. Another is that it can assert that the value given is indeed `uint16_t` for example.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thats not a reason for using a macro - thats more of a reason for using a function instead since that can actually be type-safe and a macro is not type-safe. If the function must be more generic then it can be made into a template function.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala or should i take your answer to mean you are not aware of the downsides of macros vs. functions or you are not familiar with inline functions ?

Comment: @darune unless you have noticed, the question is actually tagged *C* now.

Comment: Or it *was* before *you edited it* against the OPs intentions!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are avoiding my questions.. like i wrote, the compiler in question supports c++03 - ofc. you can stick to only c-code if you really want. If you are implying that C compilers cannot inline function you are wrong - and in the OPs case they even have an extension to force inlining. Please stop moving in circles.

Comment: You actually don't need to know the byte order of the *platform*. You need to know the byte order of the *external device* vs. the byte order of the CPU.

Comment: @tofro that's an incorrect remark. The original struct was laid out as `uint8_t`, so its byte order does not matter for this case.

Comment: I can very well see `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked to compiler documentation byte access is through intrinsics

> To access data in increments of 8 bits, use the
>   __byte() and __mov_byte() intrinsics described in Section
>   7.5.6.

If you wanted to, you could make a new type to encapsulate how bytes should be accessed - something like a pair of bytes or a TwoByte class that will have the size of 16 bits.

For inspiration take a look at how `std::bitset` template class is implemented in STL for an analogue problem. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

As I posted in my other answer, I still believe the your bitfield *could* work - even though it might be platform specific. Basicly if it works out, the compiler should put in the correct bitshift operations.

Comment: I will first try the bitfield approach. It will be platform dependent, but if it works the compiler will do all the work for me. And he __byte() intrinsic also is platform dependent.

Comment: @Muperman: I'd suggest writing a macro which chains to `__byte()` but could be replaced with something more appropriate for other platforms if the code is ported.

Answer (score -4):

The bitfield approach may work in practice. Although you do need some way to verify or make sure that it is packed in the correct way for your target platform. The bitfield approach will not be portable as you state yourself the order of bitfields is platform dependent.

Comment: I can't find the specific paragraph int he compiler-description again, but it stated, that the result of sizeof will give the size calculated in 16bit, So char has 16bit and sizeof will still return 1

Comment: I just found it:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514q/spru514q.pdf
6.4 below the note below the table

Comment: That paragraph also reads "To access
data
in increments
of 8 bits, use the
__byte()
and __mov_byte()
intrinsics
described
in Section
7.5.6."

Comment: Btw. that also tells us it is not a standard conformant c++ compiler ...

Comment: "A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8
encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined."